# Permission change to exclusively all folders (or .extension files)

Tags: permissions

I want to change permissions of all **777** folders to **755** and also change all **777 php files** to **644**.

How can I do this through shell?

P.S: all files and directories are in `www` directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can change the permissions of all **777** folders to **755** using find as below.

```
find /var/www -type d -perm 777 -print -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```

The above command will change all the directories inside `/var/www` to have the permission set as **755**. To verify it, you can use the below command.

```
stat -c "%a %n" /var/www/directory-name
```

To change the permissions of all php files, you can use the below command.

```
find /var/www/some-directory -type f -name "*.php" -perm 777 -print -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Again, you can use the `stat` command to verify if the permissions had changed.  Or you can even use,

```
ls -ld /var/www/some-directory-name
```

Both `stat` and `ls -ld` will display the octal permissions of the file.

Comment: What is the `-print` doing there?

Comment: @terdon, I just thought may be we can verify which directory's permissions actually got changed :)

Comment: Ah, indeed, fair point.

Answer (score 2):

"www" could be *anywhere* on your system, so be more specific next time.

Anyway, I am assuming you meant `/var/www`:

```
find /var/www -type d -perm 777 -print0 | xargs chmod 755
find /var/www -name "*.php" -perm 777 -print0 | xargs chmod 644
```

In the future, refer to `man find`. It's quite powerful, as you can gather.

Comment: Bear in mind that this will break on some file names, use `-print0` for `find` and `xargs -0` to avoid that.

Comment: @terdon: should we use them together? `xargs -0` will use `null` for termination, while `-print0` will not echo `null` in output.

Comment: @MohammadEtemaddar yes it will, `-print0` uses null as output separator and `-0` tells `xargs` to use null as input separator.